# How can a version controlled /bootstrap/ folder be used to sync the repository Hippo CMS?

Tags: version-control, hippocms

So I've always committed the /bootstrap/ folder to Git.
My colleagues can check it out from Git.

Now, what do they have to do to see the same latest hst:namespaces (document types), hst:configurations (sitemaps, pages, templates, containers) and contents (documents, gallery, assets) as I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to update their git repository (pull) and rebuild the project. If they are using own storage directory, they should change it by using new storage directory so everything is bootstrapped at startup, e.g.:

```
mvn clean package -Drepo.path=new_storage_path
```